# Selecting a div container

Tags: html, css

How can I select the likebtn container with CSS?

[image: selector screenshot]

I have tried several combinations, for example "#meta #likebtn{}" or "#likebtn{}" and it did not work.
Why does this work?

Comment: As you can see in the lower-right part of the screenshot the div is referred to as `div#likebtn`. Did you try that?

Comment: Did the given answer work for you? If not, do let me know :)

Answer (score 5):

First, you target it as direct as possible:

```
#likebtn {
    /* desired style changes here */
}
```

Then open your developer tools and check the style inspector; if your CSS rules are being overridden somewhere it will tell you what selector was used to override it.

For instance, this could override your rule:

```
#meta #likebtn
```

The next step is to either:

- declare your rule with the same selector *after* the earlier declaration or,
- be more precise.